# After upgrading to MUI v5 my buttons are adding a class on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My buttons looks fine when i run the app, but once i click one, all of them get this ".MuiButtonBase-root" class that is messing everything up, any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Can you add your code here? MUI `Button`s should always have `.MuiButtonBase-root` class.

Comment: I think it has something to do with this, but i only have the new @mui/material on dependencies, it should be dev?